# Removing Tkinter Objects (created in a function) in a separate function

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to be able to clear my tkinter window of all objects (with a function), and create the objects again with a function. However, I cannot access the objects created with my first function with the second function. I recreated my problem below.

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
def create():
    test = tkinter.Button(window, text="Example", command=delete)
    test.place(x=75, y=100)

def delete():
    test.place_forget()

create()
window.mainloop()
```

This returns the error - `NameError: name 'test' is not defined`

Comment: Use a class and its fields to store the objects you need to refer to later. This is not Tkinter-related, just Python basics :)

Comment: How is this, user2880853 below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick sample of how your code might look, using an object oriented structure:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyApp: # No need to inherit 'object' in Python 3
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def create_button(self):
        self.test_button = tk.Button(self.root,
                text="Example",
                command=self.delete_button)
        self.test_button.place(x=75, y=100)

    def delete_button(self):
        self.test_button.place_forget()

    def run(self):
        self.create_button()
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MyApp(root)
    app.run()
```

You create a `MyApp` object that 'owns' the button, and has methods that explicitly act on the things that it owns.  Any method of the `MyApp` object has a reference to various widgets, via the `self` argument that automatically gets sent in.

This is a lot more code than you had before, and to be honest, for what your code does right now, it's an overkill.  Malik's solution of using `global` is probably fine.  However, if you want to add more widgets, layer them out, have them interact in more complex ways etc, then using `global` can introduce hard-to-find bugs, and makes it incredibly hard to wrap your head around what's going on.

Any non-trivial use of Tkinter that I have seen has used an object-oriented style similar to the above example.

As an aside, I wouldn't create the `delete` function - using the `.config` method to set the command after you create the button would be better:

```
def create_button(self):
    self.test_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Example")
    self.test_button.config(command=self.test_button.place_forget)
    self.test_button.place(x=75, y=100)
```

Using `.config` allows you to set commands that are methods of the button you just created, which you can't do when you set the command as a part of the button instantiation.

Comment: Marked as best answer, thank you very much man! Yes, I have a large amount of code, I just wrote that as a quick example to avoid making you guys read a lot of junk. I will rewrite the code as you suggested, thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're using two different functions, you're going to need `global` variables:

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()

test = None

def create():
    global test
    test = tkinter.Button(window, text="Example", command=delete)
    test.place(x=75, y=100)

def delete():
    global test
    test.destroy() # or place_forget if you want
    window.after(5000, create) # button reappears after 5 seconds

create()
window.mainloop()
```

Your `delete` function could not destroy the button as it was only defined in the `create` function. The workaround is to create a global variable that can be accessed by both.

Comment: While I'm not downvoting, [global variables do need to be treated with a lot of care](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) so it's a little worrying that you're providing this as a solution without any caveats.  It's probably better to explicitly pass reference to the objects, i.e.  have `test` be an output of `create` and an input of `delete`, and even better to write the whole code in OO-style

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Works, but is wrong. You shouldn't encourage usage of global variables when they are not the only way to go. That's a bad programming style: involves unnecessary, unmaintainable, implicit coupling.